# Unable to compile a kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel

I am trying to build a kernel module while compiling the kernel image, by changing the config symbol value to `'m'. But I do not see any module file generated. Please let me know if I need to take some extra steps to generated a module. If I change the flag to 'y' the code works fine.

Also, in online tutorials I have seen both of the following

```
>insmod temp.ko
```

also,

```
>insmod temp.o
```

Which one is correct type for a dynamically loadable module?

Comment: Please can update question with which architecture you building, and your procedure of building kernel. so that it helps others to understand your query

Comment: i forgot to select confirm answer, I am done with it. Thanks! great to see you back :)

Comment: Thank you for remembering me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For compiling loadable kernel modules in Linux tree apply the following command

   `make modules`
2. `.ko` is the proper kernel module extension. If `.o` is tried with `insmod`, then `Invalid module format` error will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

if your module has dependencies to other modules, then:

`make modules` to build modules

`make modules_install` to install them

`modprobe temp.ko` to load temp module and it's dependencies

if your module is simple and has no dependencies, then:

`make modules` to build modules

`cd /path/to/module`

`insmod temp.ko`

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't using modules target in make.

Answer (score 0):

First, run `make menuconfig`, search the module you want to build using `/`. Next choose `'m'` or `'y'` depending on when you want to compile it as a part of the kernel or build it as a module.

(If you don't want to build the entire kernel and just a single module):
Next, in the `linux` directory (assuming you are using vanilla kernel) run the following commands which will generate the scripts and required configuration files based on your `.config`

`make prepare`

`make scripts`

Now simply build the module using:

`make M=<path/to/module/dir>`

Finally you should have a kernel object/module (.ko) in the directory if you have selected `m`

hope this helps.